# standalone Thread in webapplication with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-applications

is it possible to create a server side thread which runs on server even if the web page is closed once it is started from web page. After if i need to stop if then i open my page again and then if that thread is running the button should display stop.

for example,
i've one button in webpage. on click it a new thread will start and it will write current date and time to the file specified even if i close my web page.

Comment: And can user B stop a Thread started by User A ?

Comment: it is a single user system. Only what required is that if thread is running with specific name then when i open my web page it should provide me stop option. And if it is not running then i can start a new thread with that name.

Comment: Single user Web Apps are .... weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a thread by request, and it will continue running, after that request is handled. You can also store a reference to that thread in a static variable, so that next request would know that thread exists, and can abort it.

However, this is not a robust application design at all. IIS can recycle your application pool at any time, based on number of factors, like request count, memory usage, application running time.  When this happens, your thread will likely to be aborted in the middle of processing. So, the better design would be to have a separate windows service that handles such background operations.